# Remove the (not user? Log out) from woocomerce account dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I want to remove the (not User1? Log out) in the first line, I have tried the script to do that but it's not working. I don't want to change plugin coding to achieve the results.

Here is what I have tried. I also attached the WooComerce HTML.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var helloElement = document.querySelector(".woocommerce-MyAccount-content p:first-child");
        if (helloElement) {
            var strongElement = helloElement.querySelector("strong");
            if (strongElement) {
                var textBeforeStrong = strongElement.previousSibling.textContent.trim();
                strongElement.parentElement.innerHTML = textBeforeStrong;
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
  <p>
    Hello <strong>User 1</strong> (not <strong>User 1</strong>? <a href="#">Log out</a>)
  </p>
  <p>
    From your account dashboard, 
  </p>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`strongElement.previousSibling` is just the text node containing `Hello`  here.

You can just locate the first `strong` element inside the paragraph, and then simply remove its next siblings, as long as there are any:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var firstStrongElement = document.querySelector(".woocommerce-MyAccount-content p:first-child strong");
  if (firstStrongElement) {
    while (firstStrongElement.nextSibling) {
      firstStrongElement.nextSibling.remove();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
  <p>
    Hello <strong>User 1</strong> (not <strong>User 1</strong>? <a href="#">Log out</a>)
  </p>
  <p>
    From your account dashboard,
  </p>
</div>
```